# Does spring authorization server integrate with other IAM solutions?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server, ory, kratos

I am rather new to spring security, I have used springframework, boot and others for a while. I am working on a project for myself. I have selected ory kratos as the IAM solution. I realize that ory had hydra for oauth2 but spring auth server might be easier for me to work with and integrate into my spring project.

I see that you can configure authorization server to use jdbc or an in memory provider for user credentials.

My question is: Is it possible to integrate spring auth server with kratos?

Comment: oauth2 is a standard, so as long as they followed the standard the answer is yes. Its all in the oauth2 docs.

Comment: @Toerktumlare are there spring auth. server security providers that plugin to other IAM's I can look at? Or is it just a case of configuring auth. server to point to kratos? Only examples I have seen are, as mentioned, JDBC and in memory users/clients

Comment: Why not check the docs? There is a very nice chapter named oauth2…

Answer (score 1):

Ory Kratos is an OpenID Provider. About any other OpenID Provider can federate identities with it (either way).

Spring-authorization-server being an OpenID Provider, yes, you can use Ory Kratos as identity provider, but no, it's probably not going to make your life easier. You probably need more OAuth2 background to understand why: an OAuth2 Authorization Server is not part of your app, it is a service (most frequently a "standalone" one) that your apps talk with (either as client or resource server). Spring-authorization-server is no exception.

I suggest that you have a look at [these tutorials I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2) to get minimal OAuth2 background and to get started with OAuth2 configuration in Spring apps.

I suggest also that you compare pricing and features with other OpenID Providers (price per user can grow quickly with cloud providers).

Last, I advise that you use only libs compatible with any OpenID Provider (`spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, optionally with [this one I maintain](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) to make usage of spring-boot-starter-oauth2-X easier)